# Why is $ \sin((1-n) \cdot \frac{\pi}{2} ) = \sin((1+n) \cdot \frac{\pi}{2} )= \cos(\frac{n\pi }{ 2}) $?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I found this hint in my textbook:
$$ \sin\left((1-n) \cdot \frac{\pi}{2}\right)  = \sin\left((1+n) \cdot \frac{\pi}{2}\right) = \cos\left(\frac{n\pi}{2}\right). $$

I don't understand this at all.

Let's assume $n = 2$:
\begin{align}   
\sin\left((1-2)\cdot \frac{\pi}{2}\right) &= -1.32 \\   
\sin\left((1+2)\cdot \frac{\pi}{2}\right) &= -0.22 \\  
\cos\left(2\cdot \frac{\pi}{2}\right) &= -1.
\end{align}
Context: The goal is to simplify the following function: 
$$ \frac{2\hat{u}}{\pi}\cdot \int_{0}^{\pi/2} \cos (t)\cdot \cos(nt) \, dt = \Bigg[\frac{\sin(1-n)x}{2(1-n)}+\frac{\sin(1+n)x}{2(1+n)}\Bigg]_{0}^{\pi/2} = $$
$$ \frac{\hat{u}}{\pi}\cdot \frac{(1+n)\cdot \sin(1-n)\pi /2 + (1-n)\cdot \sin(1+n)\cdot \pi/2}{(1-n)(1+n)} $$
They end up with $$ \frac{\hat{u}}{\pi}\cdot \frac{(1+n)\cdot \cos(n\pi/2) + (1-n)\cdot \cos(n\pi/2)}{(1-n)(1+n)} = -\frac{2\hat{u}}{\pi}\cdot\frac{\cos(n\cdot\pi/2)}{(n-1)(n+1)} $$

Comment: yes I worked in radians.

Comment: I assume all of your $\Pi$s should be $\pi$?

Comment: damn.. yes let's call it a typo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This only has a chance of being true if what is meant is actually
$$ \sin ((1-n)\pi/2) = \sin((1+n)\pi/2) = \cos(n\pi/2) $$
But then it is actually true, since $\sin(\pi/2 \pm x) = \cos(x)$, and then just set $x=n\pi/2$. Your $n$ doesn't even need to be an integer.

Why your textbook was omitting the parentheses around the argument to the sines (and made the identity look like nonsense) we may never know.

Comment: I updated the question. The function came from an antiderivative which I copied from a table from the same book. After looking up for the same antiderivative in another book I saw that they messed up the parantheses.    
Thank you I really started to doubt me.

Answer (score 1):

**hint**

You just need know that

$$\sin(a)=\sin(\pi-a)=\cos(\frac{\pi}{2}-a)$$